# Почему данный код выводит вместо размера файла одно и тоже число = названию директории (в численном виде)?

Tags: linux, c

```
int Dirka(char *DirectName)
{
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *dir_element;
    er = 1;
    if ((dir = opendir(DirectName)) == NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    struct stat file;
    for (dir_elemnt = readdir(dir); dir_element != NULL; dir_element = readdir(dir))
    {
        if (strcmp(".", dir_element->d_name) && strcmp("..", dir_element->d_name))
        {
            lstat(dir_element->d_name, &file);
            if (file.st_mode == S_IFDIR)
            {
                fprintf(stdout, "%s\t<dir>\n", dir_element->d_name);
            }
            else
            {
                fprintf(stdout, "%s\t%ld\n", dir_element->d_name, file.st_size);
            }
        }
    }
    closedir(dir);  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что вы вызываете `lstat()` с именем файла относительно *current working directory (CWD)*, т.е. не учитывате значение `DirectName`
(и не проверяете результат вызова `lstat()`).

Правильный фрагмент кода вызова что-то вроде:

```
...
  char path[PATH_MAX];
  sprintf(path, "%s/%s", DirectName, dir_element->d_name);
  if (lstat(path ,&file))
    perror("Stat");
...
```

И еще одна ошибочка в проверке на тип файла.

Нужно писать:

```
...
  if ((file.st_mode & S_IFDIR) == S_IFDIR) {
     fprintf(stdout, "%s\t<dir>\n", dir_element->d_name);
...
```